# Android - Overriding ActionBar back and device back button

Tags: android

In my app I have a MainActivity and a TimerActivity.
In normal circumstances in TimerActivity the device back button and the ActionBar's up button work as they should - they lead from the TimerActivity to the MainActivity. But when I open the TimerActivity by clicking on my app's notification, the back buttons lead to the home screen instead of the MainActivity.
I would like both back buttons (device and ActionBar's up button) to always open the MainActivity - unless of course the user is in the MainActivity in which case the back button should close the MainActivity. This is how Gmail and Google Drive apps work when you open an activity through a notification and it makes the most sense.

Here's how my notification opens the activity:

```
Notification timerNotification;

mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setSmallIcon(ongoingNotificationIcon)
    .setContentTitle(ongoingNotificationContentTitle)
    .setContentText(ongoingNotificationContentText)
    .setTicker(ongoingNotificationTicker)
    .setPriority(99)
    .setOngoing(true);

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, TimerActivity.class);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
timerNotification = mBuilder.build();

startForeground(MyApplication.NOTIFICATION_ID, timerNotification);
```

I tried overriding the back button in TimerActivity like this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {    
    Intent intent_main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent_main);
}
```

But then pressing the back button again on the MainActivity returns the user to the TimerActivity (so the user is in a loop) instead of exiting the app which is the desired behavior. Also, `onBackPressed()` doesn't affect the ActionBar's up button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> onBackPressed() doesn't affect the ActionBar's up button.

The "back" button and the "up" button are two different means of navigation.

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back):

**Up**

> The Up button is used to navigate within an app based on the
>   hierarchical relationships between screens.

**Back**

> The system Back button is used to navigate, in reverse chronological
>   order, through the history of screens the user has recently worked
>   with. It is generally based on the temporal relationships between
>   screens, rather than the app's hierarchy.

So, what you're describing as your problem is actually the *recommended* way to navigate through your app.

Nevertheless, if you want your users to go to your `MainActivity` from your `TimerActivity` after pressing your `Notification`, the easiest way to implement that would be to include an `Intent` extra to check when you're launching the `Activity` from your `Notification`.

Here's an example:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, TimerActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
```

**In your `TimerActivity`**

```
private boolean mFromNotification;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (args != null) {
        mFromNotification = args.getBoolean("fromNotification");
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mFromNotification) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) does all of the back button stack building for you - you don't need to handle it yourself.

Comment: This solves the problem of the back button but the ActionBar's up button still closes the app instead of returning to the MainActivity, even though I've defined .MainActivity as the parent activity in the Manifest. As for the recommended behavior, if Gmail and Google Drive don't follow it, I guess I don't have to either.

Comment: I also did to the up button what you said to do the back button and got a working solution. TaskStackBuilder is just too complicated for me to understand right now.

Answer (score 3):

1. To override Actionbar Up button, use:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   {
       switch(item.getItemId()) {
           case android.R.id.home:
               //User clicked home, do whatever you want
               return true;
           default:        
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
   ```
2. To auto return to previous activity, please specify previous activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".SecondActivity"              
       android:label="@string/label_myLabel"
       android:parentActivityName=".FirstActivity">
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value="com.yourpackage.FirstActivity"/>
   </activity>
   ```

Comment: I've defined the parent activity in the manifest correctly, but thanks for the home button override. I combined adneal's solution with yours and got it working. you should change R.id.home to android.R.id.home

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [Notifications Setting up a regular activity PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#DirectEntry), you should use [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) to build a synthetic back stack so that your back button functions as if the user had navigated to their normally:

```
...
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
// Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
...
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

The Action Bar Up action, as you noticed, does not differ whether you are coming from a notification or not (as expected if you've set it up correctly).

Comment: The Action Bar Up action also doesn't work properly (at least in Gmail and Google Drive it always leads to the parent activity instead of closing the app like in my case)

Comment: @TimSim - then you need to follow the rest of the directions from that link on how to set up your Up button.

Comment: But I've defined the .MainActivity as the parent activity of the TimerActivity in the Manifest, and it works correctly except when opening the activity from a notification.