# Android different between onBackPressed() on back

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an app with 2 activities, the first loads data from http and display the header, the second is details of the specific header.
On the hardware back pressing from the second screen the first page do not reload, which is great.
On the action bar back, the page is reloading.

I tried to use this :

```
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.onBackPressed();
            break;
```

but it still reloading..

tried to read ll of those topics:
[Difference between actionBar back button and android back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282112/difference-between-actionbar-back-button-and-android-back-button)
[Differences between hardware back button and navigation bar back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204607/differences-between-hardware-back-button-and-navigation-bar-back-button)
[Android - Overriding ActionBar back and device back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097741/android-overriding-actionbar-back-and-device-back-button)

Any idea how can I debug or fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to override `onBackPressed` to get a consistent behavior.

Comment: Have you declared in your manifest file `parentActivity` to the activity you are trying to exit from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your workaround isn't working is that you need to simply `return` after that. When you only `break`, your code probably ends up calling 
`super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` which then reloads the first activity anyway.

```
case android.R.id.home:
    this.onBackPressed();
    return;
```

This however is not the recommended approach because it breaks the Android's navigation design pattern which outlines the difference between UP or Ancestral and Back or Temporal navigation.

> The **Up** button is used to navigate within an app based on the **hierarchical** relationships between screens. The system **Back** button is used to navigate, in reverse **chronological** order, through the **history** of screens the user has recently worked with.

More info on this at http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. And in my case affected suck thing ->
If you go back using ***navigation bar back button*** in activity which is a parent to your activity will calls **onNewIntent** method.
Unlike ***hardware back button***.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent) instead of on back pressed.

For example :

```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

And look for event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK

Answer (score 0):

If your desired behavior is no action on back button pressed, you should override `onBackPressed` and place no action in it, like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    /* do nothing */
}
```